# Restoring force of a Lennard-Jones potential

Tags: calculus, physics, classical-mechanics

Let the potential energy of a system of two atoms whose equilibrium separation is $R_0$ be given by $$U=U_0((\frac{R_0}{r})^{12} -2( \frac{R_0}{r})^{6})$$ where r is the separation at any instant.

The problem is to calculate the restoring force for this function in the form $ F=-kx$

I used the definition of force $F=-dU/dr$.but it didn't simplify in the form required. Please help me in this regard, thanks.

Comment: Make a Taylor expansion of F about $r=0$ and ignore higher orders of $r$

Comment: @Troy The potential is undefined at $r=0$

Comment: While a Taylor series will suffice, $r=0$ is _not_ the equilibrium in the Lenard-Jones potential. (In fact, the potential _diverges_ at $r=0$). So you'll need to locate this position first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The potential energy function of a restoring force is of the form $U(r)= \frac 12kr^2$ (quadratic), however this is the Lennard-Jones potential which is clearly not quadratic. See a plot here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential

The idea however is that close to the stable equilibrium point, the function looks quadratic. We can therefore take a Taylor series expansion of the potential function about the equilibrium point up to the quadratic term which approximates the oscillations in this potential well as a harmonic oscillator (which gives you your required restoring force).

First we must find the equilibrium point which can be done by setting the derivative to zero:
$$\frac {dU}{dr}=U_0 \Big( \frac{-12R_0^{12}}{r^{13}}+\frac{12R_0^6}{r^7} \Big)=0$$

$$\implies\frac{12R_0^{12}}{r^{13}}=\frac{12R_0^{6}}{r^{7}}$$
$$\implies r^6=R_0^{6}$$
$$\implies r=R_0$$
And you can show that this is a stable equilibrium by showing that $U''(R_0)>0$. We can now take a Taylor series expansion about $r=R_0$ up to the quadratic term:
$$U(r)\approx U(R_0) + U'(R_0)(r-R_0)+\frac 12U''(R_0)(r-R_0)^2$$
where $$U(R_0)=-U_0$$
$$U'(R_0)=0, \hspace{2mm} \text{(since this is an equlibrium point)}$$
$$U''(R_0)=\frac{72U_0}{R_0^2} \hspace{2mm} \text{(I'll leave this for you to show.)}$$ and so $$U(r) \approx -U_0+ \frac 12 \frac{72U_0}{R_0^2}(r-R_0)^2$$
Which finally looks like the restoring potential $U(r)=\frac 12 kr^2$ that we want. Remember still that this is all an approximation technique, the potential only looks parabolic for points close to $r=R_0$ so when enough energy is put into the system this approximation falls apart. We are now finally ready to find the restoring force, simply take the negative gradient of our potential **close** to the equlibrium:
$$F(r)= -\frac{dU}{dr}\approx-\frac{72U_0}{R_0^2}(r-R_0)$$
A restoring force with equilibrium $r=R_0$ and Hooke's constant $k=\frac{72U_0}{R_0^2}$.